# Custom block assigned to new region invalid

Tags: blocks, theming

I had created a new region to my theme "buynow" and my theme.info contains the following line

```
regions[buynow] = Buynow
```

In my custom module i had created a custom block in which i assigned the block to the region buynow

```
function buynow_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['buynow'] = array(
    'info' => t('Shoretel Buynow'),
    'status' => 1,
    'region' => 'buynow',
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

When i try to enable the module, Iam getting **The block was assigned to the invalid region and the block was disabled**

How can i set my block to the new region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
function formalter_block_info() {

 $blocks = array();

 $blocks['buynow'] = array(

 'info' => t('Shoretel Buynow'),

 'status' => 1, // This will enable your block by default, and set it to region given in 'region' option

 'region' => 'buynow', // put <machine-name of your region> in place of footer
 'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,

 'weight' => 2,

 );
return $blocks;
}
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: I tried this code, and it is working, what issue you are facing?

Comment: The block Buynow was assigned to the invalid region buynow_btn and has been disabled
this is the error am getting.

Comment: I hope you are entering right region here: 'region' => 'buynow',

Comment: Yes my new region is buynow

Comment: have you tried clearing cache

Comment: Yes i tried cc all, but its not working.

Comment: Will you please provide me the code in your custom module, and the code, where you are adding your new region. Is the new region listed on the blocks page(admin/structure/block)?

Answer (score 0):

Even though its an old issue I am pointing it to Drupal Discussion so others can benifit from it.

Here is the discussion regarding this in [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1172560) .

The problem occurs when the assigned region is not present in default themes.When we assign a region to a block through custom module it is assigned to all the available themes not just current active theme.

For example Seven is the administator theme in Drupal 7 , it has only 4 regions but default theme Bartik has more then 4 regions so if if you assign a region which is present in Bartik theme to block through custom module it cant get assigned to the same region in Seven theme as it is not present, hence the Warning will be thrown.